# Response 403 when converting curl command to Java

Tags: java, php, http, curl, http-headers

I am facing a problem with converting a curl command to Java. Below is my curl

```
curl https://api.XXXX.com/authorizations \
-u john:doe -d '' \
-H 'Accept: application/vnd.drivr.v2+json' \
-H 'Content-type: application/json'
```

and I have tried the Java equivalent this way

```
     String stringUrl = "https://api.XXXX.com/authorizations";
        URL url = new URL(stringUrl);
        URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();

        String userpass = "john" + ":" + "doe";
        //String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(new Base64().encode(userpass.getBytes()));
        String basicAuth = "Basic " + javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(userpass.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        uc.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);
        uc.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/vnd.drivr.v2+json");
        uc.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");

        System.out.println("url is: "+uc.getURL().toString()+" "+basicAuth);
        InputStream inputStreamReader = uc.getInputStream();
```

Its been almost 2 days straight with this. It always gives me 403 response. I am not sure where am I going wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your commented line looks a lot better than that XML bind thing.

Try modifying it to

```
String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(Base64.encodeBase64(userpass.getBytes()));
```

Also in the future, run your curl command with "-v" to see the request headers it is making. Then you can check the Authorization header in there and compare it to the one you're generating in your Java code.

Answer (score 0):

I can see your curl command has `-d ''` parameter. It means http POST request.

But your java code is doing `GET` request to the server. So change your java code so that it does the `POST` request. And it will solve your problem.